# Where are Ksh User-Defined Variables stored on UNIX machine?

Tags: variables, unix, memory, ksh

Where are KornShell (ksh) User-Defined Variables (UDV) stored on a AIX (Advanced Interactive eXecutive) machine?

**Sample Commands:**

```
@:/dir #variable=fooValue
@:/dir #echo $variable
fooValue
```

So is there a file on the AIX server with "fooValue" in text? Is the value stored in memory? Can the variable be sniffed out anyway?

Comment: The variables are held in the shell's RAM not the filesystem.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Do you have a reference (e.g., URL) which says this. If so then that is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: No, I don't have any. AFAIK that's the way all Unix shells work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell is a running process with its own little chunk of memory it gets dealt by the operating system.

As you define and set variables, the shell stores their names and values
inside its own process memory.

When the shell process exits, that memory is released back to the operating system, and the variables and their values are lost.

Answer (score 0):

it's certainly not stored on disk. You can access the memory region where the variables are stored using

```
extern char** environ;
```

see `man 5 environ`.

But the less higher-level way is via

```
char * getenv(char * varname)
```

which returns you the value of a single environment variable (which ought to be part of the `environ` pointer list) See `man 3 getenv`